# How to fix deserialization issue when a Property exposes a property of a child property

Tags: c#, deserialization

Lets say I have

```
Class NodeX : BaseX
{
    public Node PrimarySource {get; set;}
    public List<Node> AdditionalSources {get; set;}

    public override List<string> Keys
    {
       get { return this.PrimarySource?.Keys; } 
       set { if (this.PrimarySource != null) this.PrimarySource.Keys = value; }
        
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, If I try to deserialize a json of this format into NodeX I end up getting duplicate keys:

```
{
    "Name": "Node-X",
    "PrimarySource" : {
        "Name": "Node",
        "Path": "SomePath",
        "Keys": [
           "Key-1"
         ]
    },
    "AdditionalSources": [],
    "Keys": [
        "Key-1"
     ]
}
```

The deserialized NodeX contains 2 entries for Key-1. Is there a way to fix this?

Both NodeX and Node extend the same base class. Lets call it BaseX where

```
class BaseX
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<string> Keys {get; set;}
}

class Node : BaseX
{
   public string Path {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: How do you want to solve this? You can tell your JSON serializer to ignore the `Keys` property entirely, if that's what you want

Comment: Are you serialising to JSON here? The wording of the question is confusing.

Comment: What does your `Node` class look like?

Comment: I'm trying to deserialize a JSON input into where both NodeX and Node contain their keys properties populated in the JSON. @JohnathanBarclay

Comment: Both Node and NodeX classes extend the same base class. Edited the question to contain  those details. @canton7

Comment: What do you want this to be deserialized as? You seem to be making the assumption that `Keys` always contains the same content as `PrimarySource.Keys`. In this case, why bother deserializing `Keys` at all?

Comment: I have tried adding [JSONIgnore] tag on top of Keys in NodeX assuming that would stop deserializing keys and always read from Primarysource.Keys. But that dint seem to fix the issue. Dint quite understand what I was doing wrong here. @canton7